# How to get updates?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

When I try getting the updates I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

What should I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this is to download the failed key again. Try this command:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver ke16126D3A3E5C1192yserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <keymumber>`

Note that you need to replace  with the keynumber next to BADSIG from your error.

In this case `W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>`

it's `16126D3A3E5C1192`

Answer (score 0):

The key for the Ubuntu Extras repositories is in the package `ubuntu-extras-keyring`, which is apparently not installed on your system; install it.